# XSLT: copy node from another node, which the node referenced is calculated

Tags: xslt

in this example, the <R0050C0040> under <FRP_2><MAIN> will be NaN because the reference <R0030C0010> under <FRP_1><MAIN> is calculated. how to reference the <R0030C0010> under <FRP_1><MAIN> accurately by not writing the format-number($R0010C0030 + $R0020C0030 + $R0030C0030, '0.00') directly?

```
   <xsl:template match="FRP_1">
      <xsl:copy>
         <MAIN>
            <xsl:copy-of select="MAIN/*"/>
            <xsl:variable name="R0010C0030" select="MAIN/R0010C0030/text()"/>
            <xsl:variable name="R0020C0030" select="MAIN/R0020C0030/text()"/>
            <xsl:variable name="R0030C0030" select="MAIN/R0030C0030/text()"/>
            <xsl:variable name="R0040C0030" select="MAIN/R0040C0030/text()"/>
            <xsl:variable name="R0030C0010" select="MAIN/R0030C0010/text()"/>

            <xsl:variable name="R0030C0010" select="format-number($R0020C0030 + $R0030C0030, '0.00')"/>
            <R0030C0010>
               <xsl:value-of select="$R0030C0010"/>
            </R0030C0010>
         </MAIN>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <!-- Modify MAIN_Y1 element for specific nodes -->
   <xsl:template match="FRP_2">
      <xsl:copy>
         <MAIN>
            <xsl:copy-of select="MAIN/*"/>
 
            <!-- reference from other template: if exist in other template, will return result -->
            <xsl:variable name="R0040C0040" select="format-number(number(document('')//FRP_1/MAIN/R0030C0010), '0.00')"/>
            <R0040C0040>
               <xsl:value-of select="$R0040C0040"/>
            </R0040C0040>
         </MAIN>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

here are the XML input file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FRP_S>
   <FRP_1>
      <MAIN>
         <R0010C0030>10</R0010C0030>
         <R0020C0030>20</R0020C0030>
         <R0030C0030>30</R0030C0030>
      </MAIN>
   </FRP_1>
   <FRP_2>
      <MAIN>
         <R0010C0010>6</R0010C0010>
      </MAIN>
   </FRP_2>
</FRP_S>
```

current output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FRP_S>
   <FRP_1>
      <MAIN>
         <R0010C0030>10</R0010C0030>
         <R0020C0030>20</R0020C0030>
         <R0030C0030>30</R0030C0030>
         <R0030C0010>50</R0030C0010>
      </MAIN>
   </FRP_1>
   <FRP_2>
      <MAIN>
         <R0010C0010>6</R0010C0010>
         <R0040C0040>NaN</R0040C0040>
      </MAIN>
   </FRP_2>
</FRP_S>
```

my expected output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FRP_S>
   <FRP_1>
      <MAIN>
         <R0010C0030>10</R0010C0030>
         <R0020C0030>20</R0020C0030>
         <R0030C0030>30</R0030C0030>
         <R0030C0010>50</R0030C0010>
      </MAIN>
   </FRP_1>
   <FRP_2>
      <MAIN>
         <R0010C0010>6</R0010C0010>
         <R0040C0040>50</R0040C0040>
      </MAIN>
   </FRP_2>
</FRP_S>
```

Comment: Please provide an example of the  input and the expected result. Also please reduce the example to the minimum required to demonstrate the problem - see: [mcve].

Comment: P.S. I am guessing (!) you want to use a variable for the result of the calculation in the first step. But I don't really follow the logic here.

Comment: Who on earth thought that having two elements called `R0010C0030` and `R0030C0010` was a smart idea? The result is that it takes 5 minutes to understand your question, and that's more time than most of us are prepared to give to it.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you do something simple like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:variable name="sumFRP_1" select="format-number(sum(/FRP_S/FRP_1/MAIN/*), '0.00')" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="FRP_1/MAIN">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
        <R0030C0010>
            <xsl:value-of select="$sumFRP_1"/>
        </R0030C0010>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="FRP_2/MAIN">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
        <R0040C0040>
            <xsl:value-of select="$sumFRP_1"/>
        </R0040C0040>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result I get is slightly different from the one you show, because the sums are formatted:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FRP_S>
   <FRP_1>
      <MAIN>
         <R0010C0030>10</R0010C0030>
         <R0020C0030>20</R0020C0030>
         <R0030C0030>30</R0030C0030>
         <R0030C0010>60.00</R0030C0010>
      </MAIN>
   </FRP_1>
   <FRP_2>
      <MAIN>
         <R0010C0010>6</R0010C0010>
         <R0040C0040>60.00</R0040C0040>
      </MAIN>
   </FRP_2>
</FRP_S>
```